# Maximum number of linearly independent quadrics containing a curve in $\mathbb{P}^4$ not contained in a hyperplane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider everything over $\mathbb{C}$. My question is:

What is the maximal number $k$ of linearly independent homogeneous quadratic forms $Q_1,\dots,Q_k$ in $5$ variables such that the intersection $V(Q_1) \cap \dots \cap V(Q_k) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^4$ has a connected component that is positive dimensional and does not lie on a hyperplane?

I think the answer might be $k=6$; the example I have in mind is that $6$ linearly independent quadrics vanish on the quartic rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P^4}$.

The motivation for my guess comes from the analogous question in $\mathbb{P}^3$; we can ask for the maximal number $k$ of linearly independent homogeneous quadratic forms $Q_1,\dots,Q_k$ in $4$ variables such that the intersection $V(Q_1) \cap \dots \cap V(Q_k) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ has a connected component that is positive dimensional and does not lie in a hyperplane. Here, one can show that the answer is $k=3$, and in fact any such connected component must be a twisted cubic curve.

Update: The only nondegenerate (irreducible and not lying on a hyperplane) surface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ lying on the intersection of $3$ quadrics is a cubic scroll, which contains a quartic rational curve. Perhaps we can use the fact that that if we have some linearly independent quadrics $Q_1,\dots,Q_k$ for $k \geq 6$ containing a nondegenerate curve in their intersection, then if the intersection $V(Q_1) \cap V(Q_2) \cap V(Q_3)$ is $2$-dimensional, it must be a cubic scroll?

Update: crossposted to [this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410166/maximum-number-of-linearly-independent-quadrics-containing-a-curve-in-mathbbp)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed $k=6$; see Proposition 12.18 of [Akhil Matthew's course notes for Joe Harris' algebraic curves course](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/287y.pdf). I am still not sure whether the rational normal curve is the only extremal examples for curves!